# Styling Background-image Url

Tags: css, sencha-touch

How to style background-image url height and width

I am using sencha-touch AND building a mobileApp,
I have a view with a image - Xtype

```
    var profilePicture = {
        xtype : 'image',
        style : 'margin-top:10px;',
        id : 'profilePhoto',
        src : 'resources/images/profile.png',
        height : '104px',
        width : '84px'
    };
```

I added this image in the panel
I dynamically set the image's src in my controller with the value of json I get from the server,

src = localStorage.httpServerPrefix + profile.imageURI; // I get the image URL
   Ext.getCmp("profilePicture").setSrc(src.);

When I see in the browser 
I get like,

```
<div class="x-img" id="profilePhoto" style="margin-top: 10px; height: 104px !important; width: 84px !important; background-image: url(http://127.0.0.1:8080/Milna/user/mphoto/1?version=7); "></div>
```

Height and width of the div are set to 104px and 84px. 
My image's size is 1600px × 1200px, so that it does not fit into the above div. 
Is it possible to style the background image url???
What can I do to style the image which is coming from the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Refactored scope](http://ominian.com/2012/02/06/sencha-touch-v2-with-style/).  In this article thay have explained about the styling function.

you're styling will be more consistent, and more importantly it will make you totally look good when you restyle an entire mobile app in minutes instead of days.

> Style: 'background: resources/images/profile.png; width: 45%',

Answer (score 1):

use CSS3 -

```
div{ background-size: cover; }
```

As you are using large images in your web app. You should read on [**Adaptive Images**](http://adaptive-images.com/)

Comment: as Dipaks said, Use the background-size porperty. And after that you can use "background-position" property to position your background-image properly.

Comment: Thanku, It worked out but half of the image is visible with height:104 and width:84, when i reduce the height and width to 50px and 50px I can get the full image but I want it somewhat bigger and fullImage. what can I do ??